# .autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am implementing the Jquery UI autocomplete. I have the following code.

**Application.js**

```
 $(function() {
        function log(message) {
            $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo("#log");
        }

        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "/projectlist",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {
                        style : "full",
                        maxRows : 12,
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        var results = [];
                        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                            var itemToAdd = {
                                value : item,
                                label : item
                            };
                            results.push(itemToAdd);
                        });
                        return response(results);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Project Controller**

```
 def project_list  
    list=Project.all.map{|i|i.project_name}
    arr= [].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json
    render :json =>arr
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <input id = "tags"/>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  match '/projectlist' => 'projects#project_list'
```

What my above code should do is, list projects. However I am getting the follwoing error in firebug.

```
$("#tags").autocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error] source : function(request, response) {
```

I have also tried following the example [JQuery Ui Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) and no luck and get the same error :S

Comment: Usually the result of not loading the jquery ui js file. Make sure you have the jquery core and jquery ui js files loaded.

Comment: is jQuery-UI included in your html?

Comment: I have the following in my _form.html `<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min' %>` and still receive the same error

Comment: Maybe you don't have an up-to-date version of jquery? I updated my version and it started working like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're including the jquery & jquery-ui files in the BODY of your view (in the `_form` partial). You probably also loaded `application.js` in the HEAD (probably in your application layout) when you called `javascript_include_tag :defaults`. Instead, you should call jquery and the ui file *before* you call the defaults. Or, better yet, include them in the defaults as well by editing your application.rb file in the config folder.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above in a comment, this error is commonly seen when the jquery & jquery ui files aren't loaded properly.

Use normal HTML tags to reference them first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/jquery_core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Content/jquery_ui.js"></script>
```

... and be sure to link the core file before the ui file, as above. Reversing the order will also cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that although you've included jquery ui, it's not being loaded. Check your browsers console for javascript errors. If you're using chrome or safari the network tab of the developer tools might indicate that the jquery ui file isn't being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the reason why I was recieving this error was because of the ordering of my  the 'jquery' and 'jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min' in the application layouts file. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Rather than adding this as "an answer", this would have fit better as a "comment" on the answer that helped you. And if an answer helped you, you should click the green tick so that they get a rep boost and other users know which answer was correct